# (a) $F^{10}$ denotes a 10-dimensional vector space over F.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces

(a) $F^{10}$ denotes a 10-dimensional vector space over F. What is the number of distinct bases of $F^{10}$?

(b) What is the number of 4-dimensional subspaces of $F^{10}$?

F={0,1,a,b}

Comment: I'm guessing that $F$ is a finite field? Otherwise the answer to both questions is infinite.

Comment: Sorry, F={0,1,a,b}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Let $|F|=q$. To get a basis for $F^{10}$, you need to pick vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{10} \in F^{10}$ such that $v_1$ is not the zero vector, and $v_i$ is not in the span of $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{i-1}\}$.

You can do this in $(q^{10}-1)(q^{10}-q)(q^{10}-q^2)\ldots(q^{10}-q^9)$ ways. Note that you have to divide this number by 10! because each basis is being counted this many times.

(b) This is similar to (a). More explicitly, let's first count the number of 4-element sets $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ that are linearly independent. This is equal to $(q^{10}-1)(q^{10}-q)(q^{10}-q^2)(q^{10}-q^3)$. We have to divide this by the number of linearly independent sets $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4\}$ which form a basis of a given subspace of dimension 4. This number is equal to $(q^4-1)(q^4-q)(q^4-q^2)(q^4-q^3)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have just edited the question.

Comment: I have added that F={0,1,a,b}

Comment: What does that change? Aren't you making F a field of 4 elements?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to solve (b) as well?